# How do i add + 1 to activecell in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am kept on getting run time 13 error. all i am trying to do add 1 to activecell.

```
     dim rang as range
     rang = activecell + 1
     msgbox rang
```

Comment: Do you have Office XP Service Pack 3 installed? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/821292 -- read there, installing that update may fix your problem.

Comment: Are you trying to add the value in the cell or the location of active cell position?

Answer (score 2):

You're not setting the `rang` reference.

```
Set rang = ActiveCell
```

One problem down.

You're relying on implicit conversions and default properties, which makes it much harder than it needs to be, to understand what's going on.

```
rang.Value = CLng(ActiveCell.Value) + 1
MsgBox rang.Value
```

If that blows up with a runtime error 13, then `ActiveCell.Value` isn't an integer value. You can't legally add +1 to a `String`... Or do anything (including mere comparison) with an error value. Use `IsError` to determine if the cell contains a value you can work with, before you work with it:

```
If Not IsError(rang.Value) Then
    MsgBox rang.Value
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to reference the active cell's value, like this

```
rang = ActiveCell.Value + 1
```

Edit - Runtime error 13 is a type mismatch, basically you are trying to combine incompatible data types (assuming the active cell contains a number, not a number formatted as text). Try this.

```
Dim rang as Integer
rang = ActiveCell.Value + 1
msgbox rang
```

You can convert numbers formatted as text to numeric values by copying a cell with a one in it, then paste special, and select multiply (assuming the content is valid as a number)

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub addOne()
ActiveCell = ActiveCell.Value + 1
End Sub
```

Try This. This will simply add 1 in current value. Make sure its not a string value in active cell. Hope This help.